# Unable to fetch data using autocomplete feature

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

The data list is shown empty while I can see it on Network tab in google chrome.
I want to implement autocomplete functions to retrieve the address using Jquery. 
On the backend I am using spring boot and I am retrieving List of Address from database. 
All is fine I can fetch Json data on browser and can see it on network tab of chrome.
It might be possible there is lack of some logic to implement it correctly.
A picture would say it much better.

[json data on network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTFOU.png)

**and the front end**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang = "en">
   <head>
      <meta charset = "utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete functionality</title>
      <link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
         rel = "stylesheet">
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

      <!-- Javascript -->
      <script>
         $(function() {
            $( "#automplete-1" ).autocomplete({
                source: "/addressAutocomplete",
                 autoFocus:true,
                minLength: 2,
            });
         });
      </script>
   </head>

   <body>
      <!-- HTML --> 
      <div class = "ui-widget">
         <p>Type "a" or "s"</p>
         <label for = "automplete-1">Tags: </label>
         <input id = "automplete-1">
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

**controller**

```
  @GetMapping("/addressAutocomplete")
      @ResponseBody
      public List<Address> getSearchdata (@RequestParam(value = "term", defaultValue = "", required = false) String term){
          /*List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
          list.add("subodh");
          list.add("surender");
          return list;*/
          System.out.println("service -->"+searchService.fetchAddress().toString());
        return searchService.fetchAddress();

      }
```

**can see data on browser but unable to fetch it using autocomplete function**

[Json data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCRyN.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching data from server so you have to use ajax call something like this

```
    $("#automplete-1).on("keyup",function(){  //put different event accordingly

    $.ajax({
      url:'/addressAutocomplete',
      type:'get',
      success:function(data)
    {
      $(function() {
                $( "#automplete-1" ).autocomplete({
                    source: data,
                     autoFocus:true,
                    minLength: 2,
                });
             });
    }


    });

});
```

For more you can have a look at documentation-https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/
As your json array contains address attributes you might need to combine those attributes in a string.